# How to get the underlying file handle of a Stream?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, seek

I have an application that works with physical memory snapshots (for example, VMware VMEM files). Among other things, it can read processes/modules out of the snapshot by virtual rather than physical address. This involves reconstructing the module 4KB at a time through the page table, which, in turn, means a *lot* of calls to the Stream's Seek() method.

For reasons I'm not sure of, these calls to Seek() bog things down dramatically. As a result, I'm looking for a way around them -- or at least, a way around the managed Seek() implementation. My best guess is to PInvoke SetFilePointer and work with that directly, but in order to do that I need to get the IntPtr/SafeFileHandle for the Stream. I have a few restrictions:

1. The API I'm working with is limited to .NET 3.5, so unfortunately MemoryMappedFile isn't an option.
2. I can't use a FileStream (which already has a private SafeFileHandle field that can be accessed with reflection) or PInvoke CreateFile() to get at the snapshot another way -- the API includes a BinaryReader that has an exclusive lock on the snapshot.

Of course, unlike FileStream, neither BinaryReader nor its underlying Stream have a reference to the file handle. But certainly one must exist? In which case, how do I go about acquiring it?

Comment: What kind of `Stream`? Not all streams have file handles.

Comment: MemoryMappedFile in .NET 4.0 is just managed wrapper around the native API, you should be able to implement it without to much trouble within 3.5 (hence, i've seen many implementations out there already). That said, it sounds to me that you're mostly stuck with using the file system (apart from some smart caching). Memory mapped file by far gives you the fastest results possible in your described scenario (compared to out-of-the-box provided solutions).

Comment: @John Saunders: Thank you, your question prompted me to take a second look at the `BinaryReader` class, whereupon I realized that I simply need to downcast the `BaseStream` property to `FileStream`, then use reflection to access the `SafeFileHandle`. I'd be happy to select that as the correct answer if you want to write it up.

Comment: @Polity: And thank you for the MemoryMappedFile tip. I'll definitely look into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no file handle for `Stream` because it's an abstract class. A class implementing `Stream` may or may not use a file handle -- `FileStream` does, since it reads data from a file, but `MemoryStream`, for example, does not.

To get the underlying file handle (in this case a `SafeFileHandle`) of a `BinaryReader` whose `Stream` is a `FileStream`, use reflection to access `private SafeFileHandle _handle`, like so:

```
SafeFileHandle sfh = (SafeFileHandle)typeof(FileStream).GetField("_handle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue((FileStream)YOUR_BINARY_READER.BaseStream)
```

On a side note: neither direct calls to `SetFilePointer()` nor `MemoryMappedFile` helped in this case. It seems there's no fast way to handle random disk access at the volume I'm using it (millions of consecutive calls).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `BinaryReader` over `FileStream` you can access the `BaseStream` of the reader, cast that to `FileStream` and then use its public `SafeFileHandle` property to access the handle. Something like this:

```
FileStream stream = (FileStream)(reader.BaseStream);
//use stream.SafeFileHandle
```